# Curved bottom border with vue and svg

Tags: css, svg, vue-component, vuetify.js

In the picture you can see the Rough desired layout of SAP (rotated by 90 degrees clockwise). [image]

My first instinct would be to split it into 3 components:

1. the nav-bar on top
2. simple div containing some text
   and for the bottom I was stuck. After searching I opted for a svg path component and combined all 3 in a parent component.
   Any other components will be rendered below the curve.

So far it works. But I am curious if there are other, maybe better, solutions to this (which I am sure there are).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to achieve this would be to add an `::after` element to the navbar with some `border-radius` to make the curve. Here is an example:

```css
#navbar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 30px;
}

#navbar::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  Website
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the validation could you also please upvote my answer please ?